# Display "Complete" div when reaches a line or a variable in PHP/HTML code otherwise display "Processing'

Tags: php, html, mysql, css

I have a large MYSQL / PHP  in a while loop report being run and in many cases the report times out due to the large amount of data being calculated.

Is there a way to make have a div displaying "Processing" when the while loops is calculating and  if the report is completed , a div  "complete" is displayed.

For example: The calculation are not complete because the variable $totals are not displayed.
It is only when $Total is a rational value then "Completed" is displayed. A css solution is preferred.

Many Thanks in advance!

```
<?php
    session_start();
?>
<html>
<body id="dt_example">
<div "Processing">
<?php
    while($noticia = mysql_fetch_array($query)) { // Very long mysql query , query usually times out in this loop. Div "Processing" shown
        $Total +=$subtotal;
    }

    echo "Totals: ".$Total; //when this is executed , the report is succesful and div "Completed " is displayed
    echo "<div Completed>";

?></tbody></table></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can use ajax for interactivity.

Comment: PHP is server side. So no, you cannot do that with PHP. You can use ajax, however, and simply print "Processing" until you get your success callback.

Comment: Any recommendation for an Ajax solution?